# A way to remove all occurrences of words within brackets in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to find a way to delete all mentions of references in a text file.

I haven't tried much, as I am new to Python but thought that this is something that Python could do.

```
def remove_bracketed_words(text_from_file: string) -> string:
    """Remove all occurrences of words with brackets surrounding them, 
    including the brackets.

    >>> remove_bracketed_words("nonsense (nonsense, 2015)")
    "nonsense "
    >>> remove_bracketed_words("qwerty (qwerty) dkjah (Smith, 2018)")
    "qwerty  dkjah "
    """
    with open('random_text.txt') as file:
        wholefile = f.read()
        for '(' in
```

I have no idea where to go from here or if what I've done is right. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Can the brackets be nested (as in `"remove (the content (within) and without)"`)?

Comment: No they can't! I just do a lot of reading of research articles and want to remove all those bits that have the reference to a bajillion authors plus the date of the publication of the article. It's annoying to skim through so I just want to take all the (Author name, author name, author name, date) stuff out.

Comment: Normally, the round ones are called parentheses while the square ones are brackets (and the curly ones braces) in the American usage I'm familiar with. Your question is quite clear nonetheless.

Comment: @MadPhysicist According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket), a bracket is the most general form of a "tall punctuation mark." Brackets include round (also called "parentheses"), square, curly (also called "braces"), and angle brackets (also called "chevrons").

Comment: @DYZ.  TIL. This comment is not long enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try `re`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', 'nonsense (nonsense, 2015)')
'nonsense '
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', 'qwerty (qwerty) dkjah (Smith, 2018)')
'qwerty  dkjah '

import re
def remove_bracketed_words(text_from_file: string) -> string:
    """Remove all occurrences of words with brackets surrounding them, 
    including the brackets.

    >>> remove_bracketed_words("nonsense (nonsense, 2015)")
    "nonsense "
    >>> remove_bracketed_words("qwerty (qwerty) dkjah (Smith, 2018)")
    "qwerty  dkjah "
    """
    with open('random_text.txt', 'r') as file:
       wholefile = file.read()
    # Be care for use 'w', it will delete raw data.
    whth open('random_text.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', wholefile))
```

Comment: But beware that `re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', '(a(b)c)')` is `'c)'`.

Comment: sorry, i'm a total noob. so do i add this at the end of the function, or alone after importing the file?

Comment: @DYZ oh... I ignore this case. Could you give me some suggests if I want to use `re` to solve this?

Comment: Luckily, the OP claims that the parentheses are never nested.

Comment: @Katerina Add 're' at the top of file. I will update.

Comment: @pault - OP [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192388/a-way-to-remove-all-occurrences-of-words-within-brackets-in-a-string/54192558#comment95212420_54192388) they're trying to clean up research articles for easier reading.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have an easier time with a text editing program that handles regular expressions, like Notepad++, than learning Python for this one task (reading in a file, correcting fundamental errors like `for '(' in...`, etc.). You can even use tools available online for this, such as [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) (a regular expression tester). In RegExr, write an appropriate expression into the "expression" field and paste your text into the "text" field. Then, in the "tools" area below the text, choose the "replace" option and remove the placeholder expression. Your cleaned-up text will appear there.

You're looking for a space, then a literal opening parenthesis, then some characters, then a comma, then a year (let's just call that 3 or 4 digits), then a literal closing parenthesis, so I'd suggest the following expression:

```
 \(.*?, \d{3,4}\)
```

This will preserve non-citation parenthesized text and remove the leading space before a citation.